# Submit a rejected appilcation on playStore

Tags: android, google-play

My app was rejected because my app was using old openssl version.
I fixed this issue.
and I just Rollout my App Again but I still see that my app is rejected.
shouldn't be pending publication ?

Answer (score 1):

It stays rejected until the app gets published again. Give it sometime.

Comment: do i have to make a Rollout ? can't it be done on the preview ?

Answer (score 0):

Change SSL take 24 hour, so you must wait or please you can share your error message, or screen shot for your error.